# How to highlight certain table rows using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, mouseover

My CodePen:
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/nJzcv

So I found [this great example](http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/) of table row highlighting on CSS-Tricks. ([Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-two.php))

However I do NOT want to highlight the  my `top row`, I've tried to target only certain td's with a class name, but still not close :(

How would you go about this?

[image]

```
//Row Highlighting
$("table .active").delegate('td','mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            console.log('hovering over row');
            $(this).parent().addClass("gray-rollover");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("gray-rollover");
        }
    });

// Works but highlights all Rows
/*$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            console.log('hovering over row');
            $(this).parent().addClass("gray-rollover");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("gray-rollover");
        }
    });*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add a [table head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) around the first row and a table body around the rest:

```
<table cellpadding="12" cellspacing="1" border="1">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Icon</th>
    <th class="data-td data-name">Name</th>
    <th class="data-td data-career">Career</th>
    <th class="data-td data-company">Company</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr>
  <!-- more stuff -->
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can just target the table body with your JavaScript:

```
$("table > tbody .active").on('mouseover mouseout','td', function(e) {
```

While it's possible to do this with just JS and without altering the HTML, in this case I prefer the HTML change because it's semantically correct -- your first row isn't content, so it *should* be marked off separately as a header anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector:

```
$(this).parent().not('tr:first-child').addClass("gray-rollover");
```

This will add the class to all rows except for the first on mouseover.

[**CodePen here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjDmH)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

So you want the styles on mouse-over, except the first row. Then:

```
tr:hover td {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

tr:first-child:hover td{
    background: none;
    color: #333
}
```

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you seen the demo he's trying to copy?

Comment: @Blazemonger: it looks like OP wants to highlight rows only. That's possible with CSS